# Como escutar alterações de coordenadas em um canvas através de um dispositivo mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas

Criei este componente em Angular que possui um canvas e quando o usuário clica e arrasta nesse quadro, o canvas é preenchido com as posições das coordenadas.

Tentei reproduzir esse mesmo comportamento em um celular, porem quando eu clico e arrasto as coordenadas aparentemente não estão sendo pegas corretamente.

Como posso escutar alterações de coordenadas em um canvas através de um dispositivo mobile?

**Meu template:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas #canvas id="drawer" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Meu componente:**

```
@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  isDrawing = false;
  coordX = 0;
  coordY = 0;
  context;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer2: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.context = this.getContext2d();
    this.listenToCursorDownChanges();
    this.listenToCursorMoveChanges();
    this.listenToCursorUpChanges();
  }

  getContext2d() {
    return this.elementRef.nativeElement
      .querySelector('#drawer')
      .getContext('2d');
  }

  listenToCursorDownChanges() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      this.coordX = e.offsetX;
      this.coordY = e.offsetY;
      this.isDrawing = true;
    });
  }

  listenToCursorMoveChanges() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      if (this.isDrawing === true) {
        this.drawLine(
          this.context,
          this.coordX,
          this.coordY,
          e.offsetX,
          e.offsetY
        );
        this.coordX = e.offsetX;
        this.coordY = e.offsetY;
      }
    });
  }

  listenToCursorUpChanges() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
      if (this.isDrawing) {
        this.drawLine(
          this.context,
          this.coordX,
          this.coordY,
          e.offsetX,
          e.offsetY
        );
        this.coordX = 0;
        this.coordY = 0;
        this.isDrawing = false;
      }
    });
  }

  listenToTouchEvents() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener(
      'touchmove',
      (e) => {
        const touch = e.touches[0];
        const mouseEvent = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
          clientX: touch.clientX,
          clientY: touch.clientY,
        });
        this.drawLine(
          this.context,
          mouseEvent.clientX,
          mouseEvent.clientY,
          mouseEvent.offsetX,
          mouseEvent.offsetY
        );
      },
      false
    );
  }

  drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.moveTo(x1, y1);
    context.lineTo(x2, y2);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }
```

Estou usando a função `listenToTouchEvents()` quando há toques na tela e aparentemente os valores the client x e offset estão corretos e passados para drawLine, mas aparentemente ainda tem algo errado e meu canvas não está sendo pintado.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que tenha faltado escutar alguns outros eventos de touch. Você pode fazer uma leitura da seguinte referência [MDN: Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Para entender melhor o problema eu apliquei seu código aqui e testei via devtools do Microsoft Edge. Realmente o touch não funciona. Então fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
listenToTouchEvents() {
  this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    if (touch) {
      this.coordX = touch.clientX;
      this.coordY = touch.clientY;
      this.isDrawing = true;
    }
  });

  this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener(
    'touchmove',
    (e) => {
      const touch = e.touches[0];
      // desenha desde a coordenada inicial/anterior
      // até o touch atual
      this.drawLine(
        this.context,
        this.coordX,
        this.coordY,
        touch.clientX,
        touch.clientY
        );
      
        // o ultimo local do touch atual para uso no proximo movimento
        this.coordX = touch.clientX;
        this.coordY = touch.clientY;

    },
    false
  );

  this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    if (this.isDrawing) {
      this.isDrawing = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Realmente o que falta é iniciar o touch com touchstart, efetuar pequena alteração no touchmove e também fazer o touchend.

Ah! **Não esqueça** de chamar o método `listenToTouchEvents` no `ngAfterViewInit`.

Na minha resposta não tratei o evento `touchcancel`, mas conforme o artigo que referenciei acima, é importante tratar esse evento para quando, por exemplo, o touch do usuário vai pra UI do navegador.

Após essas alterações, passei a conseguir desenhar via touch no devtools do Microsoft Edge.